# NumericProperty does not change value after clearing screen

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having this small issue with Kivy currently. I'm working on a POS system and I am keeping track of the total with a variable named `total` that is a NumericProperty in the `MyApp` class. When I add a function that resets it to 0, the `total` variable stays 0 and will not add again. After a bit of troubleshooting, I've figured out that if I exclude the line `self.clear_widgets()`, it works as intended however I do need this line. Is there any reason why this happens?

I have provided a simple example code below to demonstrate the issue. Any help would be appreciated!

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def add(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().total += 1

    def set_0(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().total = 0
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Label(text = str(App.get_running_app().total), font_size = 50))
        self.add_widget(Button(text = 'Add 1', size_hint = (0.2,0.1), pos_hint = {'x': 0.3, 'y': 0.2}, on_release = self.add))

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    total = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<WindowManager>:
    MainScreen

<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: str(app.total)
            font_size: 50
        Button:
            text: 'Add 1'
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.3, 'y': 0.2}
            on_release:
                root.add()
        Button:
            text: 'Set to 0'
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.2}
            on_release:
                root.set_0()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around this issue. I created another `FloatLayout` with an id of `list` inside my `MainScreen` and placed only the widgets I needed to remove inside this `FloatLayout`. So when I add the line `self.ids.list.clear_widgets()`, it doesn't affect the `total` variable.

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def add(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().total += 1

    def set_0(self, *args):
        App.get_running_app().total = 0
        self.ids.list.clear_widgets()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    total = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**.kv**

```
<WindowManager>:
    MainScreen

<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        id: list
        size_hint: 0.16,0.81
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: str(app.total)
            font_size: 50
        Button:
            text: 'Add 1'
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.3, 'y': 0.2}
            on_release:
                root.add()
        Button:
            text: 'Set to 0'
            size_hint: 0.2,0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.2}
            on_release:
                root.set_0()
```